# functools.partial and generators

Tags: python, generator, functools

I am trying do the following:

```
import functools

class TestClass():
    def method(self, n):
        for i in xrange(n):
            yield i

# This works 
for x in TestClass().method(10):
    print x

# This gets a TypeError: functools.partial object not iterable
for x in functools.partial(TestClass().method, 10):
    print x
```

What wrong there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`functools.partial` creates an [object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#partial-objects) that behaves like a new function that mimics the old function with some arguments 'frozen'. So you have to actually call this new function to get the same output:

```
for x in functools.partial(TestClass().method, 10)():
    print x
```